# What context to use in Multi activity android app?

Tags: android

I'm badly confused and hope to get your help understanding this concept.

I have an app with 3 activities, splash, login and main and the main activity is a multi fragment drawer activity that uses sqlite.

In my fragments i need to use context many places. I used to have a static context in my main activity defined and passed that around but in another questions someone suggested not to use static context to avoid leaks and i took the advice.

I had to change a few things and got things working. I use getapplicationcontext() but now my application now consistently crashes. The crashes are more prominent when the app is put in background.

My question is, which activity's context should i be using to start with? Splash? Login or main?  How would you get access to the context in resume?

Thanks

Comment: When you're in an `Activity`, use the `Activity` - `this`, or `MyActivity.this`, as needed - it is a `Context`. When you're in a `Fragment`, use `getActivity()`. You probably aren't doing anything yet that would necessarily need `getApplicationContext()`. Definitely don't keep a static `Context` reference.

Comment: Thanks! I am only 2 months into learning android.... It's very confusing...Why would i not need getapplicationcontext ()? What specifically needs getapplicationcontext() and not getactivity () for example?

Comment: Most of the time, you'll just wanna use the current `Activity`  if you're in one, or in anything inside of one, like a `Fragment` or `View`. Using `getApplicationContext()` will give you a `Context` that'll last for the whole app lifetime, which is useful for certain things, but it won't have certain things necessary for, e.g., some UI components, like themes and windows. [This page](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/) might help to shed some light on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in A fragment you can use **getActivity()** to access its container activity context.

If you are try to access activity context from an adapter class or dialog, you must pass the activity context to the constructor of the adapter class or dialog

If you are in an activity you can use **this** or **yourActivity.this** as per the situation.

For example

1)If you want to access activity context from **onResume()** or **onCreate()** you can simply use **this**.

2)If you are try to access activity context from an inner class like retrofit call then you must use **yourActivity.this** for activiy context